# CSS - Position:absolute creats float:left scenario.. How do I fix it?

Tags: html, css

I have this scenario where I am trying to do two canvas with layers so I have to use `position` and whatnot.. but then.. the things below it... are hidden below the canvas. How do I make it so what comes next in the DIV is at the BOTTOM of the canvas?

Here is the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qtjua/

Comment: Underneath the canvas (outside of) or literally aligned to the bottom of the canvas (inside of)? There's a difference here though most refer  to "underneath."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the 'width' & 'height' of your canvas to '#screen'.

```
#screen {
 position: relative;
 border: 4px solid #333;
 /* New stuff */
 width: 512px
 height: 352px;
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/THkmG/3/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Argh. How did I not catch this. Rookie mistake. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. And don't worry, all of us make small mistakes like this all the time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes your "Hello World." message is going behind, Since your `<div id="screen">` is having the `position:relative;` and your convas height is 352px, so you can use the margin top of 252px in your message div. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>stackoverflow</title>
<style type="text/css">

#screen {position:relative;border:4px solid #333;}
#canvas {
            background:#ABABAB;
            margin:0;padding:0;
            width:512px;
            height:352px;
            }
</style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="screen">
 <canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="352" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>

 <canvas id="drawing" width="512" height="352" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>

</div>
<div style="float:left; margin: 352px 0 0;">Hello World.</div>
</body>
</html>
```